# Sharing package between Xcode project and Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to share a dependency between my the targets of my Xcode project and a Swift Package (part of the same project) but I'm getting a duplicate symbols error with both dynamic and static targets.

I have 3 targets: `App` - Cocoa Touch, `Module A` - Static Framework, `Module B` - Static Framework, and a Swift Package called `shared` (produces a static library).

I'm trying to share `RxSwift` between all the targets and the `shared` package.

Is there any recommended approach for this? Also, I'm curious if dynamic or static frameworks are more recommended.

**This is how my project looks like:**

[image]

**Here's how the dependency graph looks like:**

- App -> Authentication, Core
- Authentication -> Core, ApiClient
- Core -> ApiClient

Here's my **Package.swift**

```
let package = Package(
name: "ApiClient",
platforms: [.iOS(.v12)],
products: [
    .library(name: "ApiClient", targets: ["ApiClient"]),
],
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift.git", from: "5.0.0"),
],
targets: [
    .target(name: "ApiClient", dependencies: ["...", "RxSwift"]),
    .testTarget(name: "ApiClientTests", dependencies: ["ApiClient"]),
]
)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to reuse RxSwift in both my Swift Package and other targets but I get duplicate symbols error for RxSwift.

Comment: What is your definition of a target?  A static framework is a target?  RxSwift is a target?  I don't understand your question.

Comment: @ElTomato I've added some details